# Apply template to nodes that have children with attribute

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'd like to apply a template to nodes that have children with a specified attribute, and I'm curious if it's possible with a `<template match=...`

So if i have an input xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<parent-node>
    <child-node>
        <label>value1</label>
        <name>name1</name>
        <desc src="anything">description1</desc>
    </child-node>
    <child-node>
        <label>value2</label>
        <desc>description2</desc>
    </child-node>
    <some-node>
        <name>name3</name>
        <desc src="something">description3</desc>
    </some-node>
</parent-node>
```

the required template will be applied to the nodes that have `desc` children with `src` attribute defined, eg. the first and last nodes:

```
<child-node>
    <label>value1</label>
    <name>name1</name>
    <desc src="anything">description1</desc>
</child-node>
<some-node>
    <name>name3</name>
    <desc src="something">description3</desc>
</some-node>
```

The best i have so far is a template matching the nodes that have `desc` children, and the rest (testing if any of the `desc` nodes have `@src`) is inside the template, in an `xsl:choose` clause:

```
<xsl:template match="*[desc]">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="desc[@src]">
            <xsl:element name="node-with-src">
                [...]
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="node">
                [...]
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

By having such a template, i could leave but the `otherwise` part inside this template, and anyway, it would be a lot nicer.

Thank you in advance for every answer!

**Edit**
I'd prefer a 1.0 solution, but it's not a criteria.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More complex (nested) predicates are allowed. Use this:

```
<xsl:template match="*[desc[@src]]">
```

And a corresponding template for the nodes without a `src` attribute:

```
<xsl:template match="*[desc[not(@src)]]">
```

For example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="*[desc[@src]]"> 
        <xsl:element name="node-with-src"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[desc[not(@src)]]">
        <xsl:element name="node"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to:

```
<parent-node>
    <child-node>
        <label>value1</label>
        <name>name1</name>
        <desc src="anything">description1</desc>
    </child-node>
    <child-node>
        <label>value2</label>
        <desc>description2</desc>
    </child-node>
    <some-node>
        <name>name3</name>
        <desc src="something">description3</desc>
    </some-node>
</parent-node>
```

Output:

```
<node-with-src/>
<node/>
<node-with-src/>
```

Comment: awesome! thank you a lot, mostly this `<xsl:template match="*[desc[not(@src)]]">` part, i was going crazy because of it, and i couldn't phrase the question right!